# Can't find where __put_user_1 is defined

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, c

I have been going through the linux kernel module programming guide, and I decided to find out how put_user(*(msg_Ptr), buffer) works. After all macro expansion is done, it appears that this inline assembly will put __pu_val into the buffer in userspace. I have put this in my program.

```
asm volatile("call __put_user_1" : "=a" (__ret_pu)   : "0" (__pu_val), "c" (buffer) : "ebx");
```

Looking through the kernel code, there only appears to be one mention of this __put_user_1 function, in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-37/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h. This is just as an external function prototype:

```
/*
 * Strange magic calling convention: pointer in %ecx,
 * value in %eax(:%edx), return value in %eax. clobbers %rbx
 */
extern void __get_user_1(void);
```

I can't see where this is defined anywhere, but Module.symvers has the __get_user_1 symbol as in the kernel:

```
0x167e7f9d  __get_user_1    vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL
```

My goal is to be able to put the put_user code in my source so I can learn how exactly the kernel can interact with userspace, but I am not having much success.

Comment: Look [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=__put_user_1).  It's referenced in several .c files also.  You probably don't have full kernel sources installed...  just the kernel headers.

Comment: @hbdgaf - Hi, I did look there. The other references just say EXPORT_SYMBOL(__put_user_1), which I had already guessed. There are also two macros, but I don't believe they are expanded in my code. After all, the code works when I jump to symbol __put_user_1.

Comment: My bad...  it's in [put_user.S](https://lkml.org/lkml/2004/1/23/108) - and ASM file that doesn't appear to be indexed by things that index kernel sources much.  Still just a macro or static definition.  Probably could have been put in a C file and used an inline assembly declaration instead of assembling it then linking against it just for clarity.

Comment: @hbdgaf - Aah, that's great! I can see a putuser.S in linus' repository, which appears to have the assembly here: goo.gl/oy1wSt. I guess all I need to do now is find out how to link it with, or include it in, my module.

Comment: I'm done.  If you want someone to read the entirety of the kernel tree, makefiles, build scripts, and use google a bit for you - then you shouldn't be doing anything that requires the answer to what you are asking.

Comment: @hbdgaf - Thanks for your input. Anyway, I have solved the problem now, after modifying and including getuser.S.

Answer (score 0):

it's in [put_user.S](https://lkml.org/lkml/2004/1/23/108) - and ASM file that doesn't appear to be indexed by things that index kernel sources much.  Still just a macro or static definition.  Probably could have been put in a C file and used an inline assembly declaration instead of assembling it then linking against it just for clarity.
                    – RobotHumans